# Formation of hypofluorite from F2 and hydroxide

Tags: redox, halogens

Why $\ce{FO-}$ can't form in reaction of $\ce{F2}$ with $\ce{OH-}$ but $\ce{ClO-}$ can form on reacting $\ce{Cl2}$ with $\ce{OH-}$?

Is $\ce{FO-}$ very unstable?

I know that fluorine can't have positive oxidation state that's why it don't behave like chlorine but isn't it good thing as now it will attract electron cloud from oxygen making it partially positive charged while chlorine would make oxygen partially negative charged because oxygen can pull electrons from chlorine.

Positively charged oxygen in case of $\ce{FO-}$ would have higher attraction for electron as compared to negatively charged oxygen in $\ce{ClO-}$ and hence there should be no reason for $\ce{FO-}$ to not form in reaction of $\ce{F2}$ with $\ce{OH-}$.  $$\ce{F2 + 2 OH-(aq) -> 2F- + OF2 + H2O}$$ $$\ce{Cl2 + 2 OH-(aq) -> Cl- + ClO- + H2O}$$

Comment: Consider the strength of the O-F bond

Comment: Your last paragraph answers it you just draw a wrong conclusion. F is more electronegative than O; Cl is similar or less than O. Hence different behavior. Explanations help understand observations not vice versa .  It is reasonable that a group has similar properties but a Leap to assume the same.